Can we use factor models for estimating intraday/high-frequency returns?
Is it sensible to use Fama-French-style factor models for intraday (i.e. high-frequency: hourly, minute, second, etc.) return estimation (albeit using different factors to FF)?
If so, which factors are likely to be important?
If not, then what are the best (or standard) models out there for this use case?
I'd greatly appreciate any feedback, including any available literature sources.
Thank you very much!

This might answer your question https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0304407620300129
